# How to setup ConTeXt to place a blank line between paragraphs?

Tags: context, paragraphs, vertical-spacing

In ConTeXt, if I have code like this, it just displays the three lines, with no blank space between:

```
\starttext
    This is a paragraph.

    This is another paragraph.

    This is yet another paragraph.
\stoptext
```

How can I get ConTeXt to know these are different paragraphs and to place a blank line between paragraphs, so readers can see these are paragraphs?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Spaces between paragraphs are handled via `\setupwhitespace`. Since you need a line...

```
%\setuppapersize[A6]
\setupwhitespace[line]
\starttext
De pie, luchar, que vamos va a triunfar. Avanzan ya banderas de unidad.

Y tú vendrás marchando junto a mí y así verás tu canto y tu bandera florecer\unknown
\stoptext
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

ConTeXt is based on TeX, so TeX primitive concept is possible too:

```
\parskip=\baselineskip
\starttext
    This is a paragraph.

    This is another paragraph.

    This is yet another paragraph.
\stoptext
```

Comment: Sorry I downvoted. In general, it is a bad idea to use TeX global formatting commands in ConTeXt as it can lead to hard to debug situations. The correct way is to use `\setupwhitespace`.

Comment: @Aditya This is opinion based. Try to use `\tracingall` before `\setupwhitespace`. You will see 63 lines in the log file. But when using `\parskip=` then you get only 3 lines in the log file (about setting to the primitive register). IMHO it is much more comfortable to see three lines than 63 lines when debugging.

Comment: I agree on both counts. My  recommendation not to do this is opinion based. And using a primitive `\parskip` is simpler to understand than using a high-level interface. However, there is a reason that context uses 63 lines to simply set `\parskip`. In my opinion, a user who wants to understand what is happening behind the scenes should use close to "close to metal" macro package like plain, eplain, or optex; a user who wants the convenience of a consistent user-interface should use context. However, mixing plain tex ideas in context can lead to hard to debug situations.

Comment: Fewer line when you enable tracing is a weak argument to prefer `\parskip` over `\setupwhitespace` and while the results are the same in your minimal example there are cases where the output is wrong. A few of these cases are (a) when you enable the grid mechanism where ConTeXt ensures the added space is either a half or a full line, (b) when you change the bodyfont (`\setupbodyfont[...]`) for a environment (e.g. block quotes) the space is adjusted to the current font size (c) when you change the baseline distance (`\setupinterlinespace[...]`) the space is adjusted to the new distance.